# CloudFormation - Better Discovery of EC2 Subnets/AZs for RDS DBSubnetGroup lists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

`cfn-lint` complains about hard-coding Availability zones when done this way:

```
Resources:
  SubnetWest2a:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-west-2a
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref GlobalVPC

  SubnetWest2b:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-west-2b
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref GlobalVPC

  SubnetWest2c:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-west-2c
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref GlobalVPC
```

So I did it this way instead:

```
Resources:
  #...
  SubnetWest1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref GlobalVPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region'

  SubnetWest2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref GlobalVPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 1
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region'

  SubnetWest3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref GlobalVPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 2
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
```

But the caveat being from [Fn::GetAZs docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html):

> Similarly to the response from the describe-availability-zones AWS CLI command, the order of the results from the Fn::GetAZs function is not guaranteed and can change when new Availability Zones are added.

The stanza that depends on these Subnets and CIDR blocks is:

```
GlobalDBSubnetGroup:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
  Properties:
    DBSubnetGroupDescription: Multi-AZ RDS subnet group
    SubnetIds:
      - !Ref SubnetWest1
      - !Ref SubnetWest2
      - !Ref SubnetWest3
```

Given these two mutually exclusive *best practice hints*, is there a better way to discover (or a better way to *create* this collection of interdependent resources for multi-AZ RDS) these and also get deterministic results every time this stack is run?

Comment: Using the `GetAZs` collection is the way to go for referencing AZ's in CF. While the statement may be true about "Ordering could be affected" For 5+ years I've been managing hundreds of CF stacks with countless VPC's and have yet to encounter an issue with the ordering (IE: new AZ's have always been appended in regards to the naming convention and ordering). I'd always caution with "run changesets before deploying stack updates" and should the ordering change, a subnet replacement with dependent resources would cause an error (rollback) and not bork your stack and give  you a chance to fix.